# Microsoft Work Wildcard find all phrases that match

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, regex, microsoft-word-2003, wildcards

I have been trying this for several days and I am coming up empty. I am simply trying to match a phrase that contains "v." within it, surrounded by newlines and em or en dashes.

Plain english expression would be:

```
(NEWLINE or CARRIAGE RETURN) (any number of words) v. (any number of words) -
```

However, Word seems to find ALL matches, not the smallest match, so if I do something like this:

```
[^13^11]{1}?{1,} v. ?{1,}[^+^=]
```

I will get dozens if not hundreds of bad matches.

Here is some sample text to search on:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
>   dolore magna aliqua.
>
> False Positive v. Other False Positive
>
> Something v. Something - Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud
>   exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> Longer Name Co. v. Other Long Name Co.
>   - Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
>   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
>   cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
>   qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
>   est laborum.

I want the search to match "Something v. Something" and "Longer Name Co. v. Other Long Name Co." and nothing else. I do not want to match "False Positive".

Comment: Using your regex (I added a regular hyphen to the m-dash and n-dash) and your sample text in Word 2007 I get exactly those matches and no false positives. What would be an example of a bad match in your sample text?

Comment: Edited to include a possible false positive. Does Word have an "exclude" for the caret+unicode characters? When I run the [!^13] to attempt to include all characters except newline, it ignores the caret+unicode form and excludes ^,1,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now see how false positives are behaving. Trying to exclude `^13` would seem to be the way to go, but I can't see any way to accomplish that.

I think that your need exceeds the capabilities of Word. It seems to have a very poor "wildcard search" which does not qualify to be called a regular expression search.

Out of curiosity, I tried your sample text in OpenOffice.org Writer and this regular expression seems to do exactly what you're looking for:

```
^.+ v. [^-–]+ [-–]
```